# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for :::: foreach($field_length_array as $fieldname => $maxlength) {

Tags: php, function, foreach, arguments

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), ::: error for foreach argument it seems all ok for me

```
function check_required_fields($required_array){
    $fields_errors = array();
    foreach($required_array as $fieldname) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != 0))
            { $field_errors[] = $fieldname; }
    }
    return $field_errors;
}
```

bellow argument gives the error foreach($field_length_array as $fieldname => $maxlength) {

```
 function check_max_field_lengths($field_length_array) {
        $field_errors = array();
            foreach($field_length_array as $fieldname => $maxlength) {
            if(strlen(trim(mysqli_prep($_POST[$fieldname]))) > $maxlength) {
            $filed_errors[] = $fieldname;}
        }
        return $field_errors;
    }
```

Comment: What is `$field_length_array`? Apparently it's not an array.

Comment: When you call the function, what value do you pass?

Answer (score 0):

may be because of invalid array "**$field_length_array**" that you are passing for this function `check_max_field_lengths()`

use `print_r()` to check, whether $field_length_array has a same desired value or not

```
echo "<pre>; print_r($field_length_array); echo "</pre>";

 **or** dd($field_length_array).
```